# Price indexing timeseries data

Tags: r, indexing

I'm new to the R coding community and as I am learning I ran into an issue I haven't been able to crack. I'm sure this is a walk in the park for most of you so I hope someone could find the time to help me out.

I have a set of currency pairs downloaded from FRED using the R getSymbols function. Then I combined three of these pairs into one dataframe ("data")

What I would like to do is create an index of these three variables in order to be able to directly compare their performance over the period of time. For example, this is my original dataset;

```
               EXJPUS    EXCHUS  EXCAUS
1981-01-01     202.3667  1.5518  1.1909

1981-02-01     205.7167  1.6131  1.1984

1981-03-01     208.7918  1.6314  1.1914
```

From this original dataset, I'd like to create a dataset that contains the values of (current value/first value)*100 = index value for example with EXJPUS: (208.7918/202.3667)*100 = 103.175

If I could implement this calculation for all three variables, I'm hoping to get a result table that looks something like this;

```
               EXJPUS    EXCHUS  EXCAUS
1981-01-01     100.000   100.000 100.000

1981-02-01     101.655   103.950 100.630

1981-03-01     103.175   105.130 100.042
```

If there is only one variable, I'm able to use the as.numeric function to extract the first value and then divide all other values by the value given from the as.numeric function. However, with multiple variables this doesn't seem work.

Can someone please give me some guidance or a suggestion on this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I've assumed you want to do this in R, but as you didn't provide a language tag, this is a guess. Providing the proper language does immensely help people finding your question.

Comment: `apply(data, 2, function(x) x / x[1] * 100)`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to perform your task, one is to use the `apply` function:

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) x / x[1] * 100)
            EXJOUS   EXCHUS   EXCAUS
1981-01-01 100.0000 100.0000 100.0000
1981-02-01 101.6554 103.9503 100.6298
1981-03-01 103.1750 105.1295 100.0420
```

We could also use the `dplyr` package, this approach allows you to retain the base value and the indexed value:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate_all(funs(pindex = . / .[1]))

    EXJOUS EXCHUS EXCAUS EXJOUS_pindex EXCHUS_pindex EXCAUS_pindex
1 202.3667 1.5518 1.1909      100.0000      100.0000      100.0000
2 205.7167 1.6131 1.1984      101.6554      103.9503      100.6298
3 208.7918 1.6314 1.1914      103.1750      105.1295      100.0420
```

Comment: I get `no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "zoo"` for the dplyr code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is an xts or zoo object, the sweep operator can be used to divide all rows by the first row thusly (and then multiply by 100):

```
zoo.mat <- 
structure(c(202.3667, 205.7167, 208.7918, 1.5518, 1.6131, 1.6314, 
1.1909, 1.1984, 1.1914), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1981-01-01", 
"1981-02-01", "1981-03-01"), c("EXJPUS", "EXCHUS", "EXCAUS")), index = 1:3, class = "zoo")

 100*sweep(zoo.mat, 2,  zoo.mat[1,] , "/")

    EXJPUS   EXCHUS   EXCAUS
1 100.0000 100.0000 100.0000
2 101.6554 103.9503 100.6298
3 103.1750 105.1295 100.0420
```

<strike>I think the `apply` solution requires less fiddling if you want the row indices.</strike> After further exploration the `sweep` and the `apply` methods seem to do equally well with a proper zoo object:

```
library(zoo)
zoo.mat <- zoo(cbind(EXJPUS = c(202.3667, 205.7167, 208.7918), EXCHUS = c(1.5518, 1.6131, 1.6314), EXCAUS = c(1.5518, 1.6131, 1.6314)), as.Date(c("1981-01-01", "1981-02-01", "1981-03-01")))
100*sweep(zoo.mat, 2,  zoo.mat[1,] , "/")
#-----
             EXJPUS   EXCHUS   EXCAUS
1981-01-01 100.0000 100.0000 100.0000
1981-02-01 101.6554 103.9503 103.9503
1981-03-01 103.1750 105.1295 105.1295
```

Comment: If `zoo.mat` is a zoo series `library(zoo); zoo.mat <- 
zoo(cbind(EXJPUS = c(202.3667, 205.7167, 208.7918), 
EXCHUS = c(1.5518, 1.6131, 1.6314), 
EXCAUS = c(1.5518, 1.6131, 1.6314)), 
as.Date(c("1981-01-01", "1981-02-01", "1981-03-01")))` then the output of `sweep(...)` will also be a zoo series having the same time index (as opposed to the output shown).

Comment: I tested on a zoo object which I will add as an edit and that was (and is) the output. Apparently only zoo-indexes that are Date class get handled in that manner.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the object I used was malformed since neither of hte methods suggested by bouncyball work with my object.

Comment: It works for me: `library(zoo); time(zoo.mat) <- as.POSIXct(time(zoo.mat)); 100*sweep(zoo.mat, 2,  zoo.mat[1,] , "/")`

Comment: I get `Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time(zoo.mat)) : 'origin' must be supplied`. I made the zoo object with as.zoo and the values were encapsulated in the dimnames rather than the index. I suppose there is a lesson to be learned.

Comment: What do you mean you made the zoo object with as.zoo?  I tried it both zoo.mat as defined in the answer and as defined in my comment above and  no errors were produced.

Answer (score -1):

```
EXJOUS <- c(202.3667, 205.7167, 208.7918)
EXCHUS <- c(1.5518,1.6131,1.6314)
EXCAUS <- c(1.1909,1.1984,1.1914)

z<-data.frame (EXJOUS, EXCHUS, EXCAUS)
rownames(z) <- c('1981-01-01', '1981-02-01', '1981-03-01')

x<-z[1,]/z[1,]*100
for (i in 2:nrow(z))
 {x<-rbind(x,
 z[i,]/z[1,]*100)
 }
x
```

Comment: That's fairly likely to be a zoo/xts object.